# Is this the same as "what job should I take"?

Tags: discussion

For the purpose of determining on-topic/off-topic is this question [Weighing pros and cons of quitting against other life circumstances](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/weighing-pros-and-cons-of-quitting-against-other-life-circumstances) fundamentally any different than one asking "what job should I take"?

Comment: It really is not.  Should i quit my job is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to rewrite the question down to its simplest form:

> **Can I quit anyway?**
>
> I know that [I shouldn't resign before finding another job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/), but I really don't like my job. Is it okay to leave anyway?

This is looking for confirmation of the asker's beliefs, not for actual constructive advice. As discussed in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This is definitely not practical or answerable.